# What mean "the server tag is not well formed", what happen with this button?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, eval

This is my button:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkButton" 
    OnClientClick="showEnroll(this,true,'<%# Eval("EventId") %>'); return false"      
    runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("EventId") %>'  />
```

This is the error: "The server tag is not well formed"

Comment: It means you have too many conflicting quotes in your `OnClientClick`. You should do this in the ItemDataBound event in the code behind, it'll be much easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the markup is invalid, and it's because of the inline databinding expressions. Something like this should work better:

```
OnClientClick='<%# string.Format("showEnroll(this, true, \'{0}\'", Eval("EventId")) %>'
```

**Note:** I have not validated the above code. It is intended to illustrate a concept, and may need tweaking.

Answer (score 1):

In your binding (i.e. `RowDataBound` for a grid view), add the logic like this:

```
// Attempt to find the control
var theLinkButton = e.Row.FindControl("lnkButton") as LinkButton;

// Only try to use the control if it was actually found
if(theLinkButton != null)
{
    // Grab the event ID from wherever here

    // Set the OnClientClick attribute here
    theLinkButton.Attributes.Add("onClientClick", 
        "showEnroll(this,true,'" + theEventId.ToString() + "'); return false");
}
```